# How can I insert in Wagtail the buttons to add and edit foreign key value like Django admin panel?

Tags: django, django-admin, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I would like to have in my **Wagtail** Admin Panel these buttons that are present in the Django Admin Panel.

[image: DjangoAdmin buttons]

Unfortunately I didn't find anything related.

### EDIT

This is the editor in Wagtail

[image: WagtailAdmin Panel]

As you can see there are no buttons to add partner using a pop up action.

Comment: Just a reminder to follow the question guidelines and embed your images if possible.

Comment: I'm checking this https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/tips_and_tricks/reversing_urls.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not super clear what you want to do, maybe update the question with more details.

Nonetheless you are probably looking for either Wagtail's ModelAdmin feature that allows arbitrary editing, viewing and management of any model within the Wagtail admin.

https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html

You may also want to understand the way that Wagtail works with Modelcluster to allow for editing and managing of foreign key related models. This works in ModelAdmin and other parts of the editing interface.

https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/panels.html#inline-panels